# iPhone JSON Parse Problem

Tags: iphone, json

I'm working with parsing JSON into my app and am running into some issues pulling in just one section of it. For some reason, it seems to be going through my whole JSON feed, logging NULL values except for the one I specify.

Any advice? Thanks for the help!

My Method:

```
-(void)loadStats {
NSDictionary *totalsfeed = [self downloadTotals]; 
NSArray *totals = (NSArray *)[totalsfeed valueForKey:@"totals"];  
NSLog(@"NEW TOTALS: %@", [totals valueForKey:@"d_monthly_total"]); 
}
```

Console Results:

```
2011-08-30 11:35:38.096 App Name [9142:16507] NEW TOTALS: (
"<null>",
"<null>",
2,
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>"
)
```

JSON Feed

```
{
    "totals": [
        {
            "ab_grand_total": "2217"
        },
        {
            "d_grand_total": "1096"
        },
        {
            "d_monthly_total": "2"
        },
        {
            "ab_monthly_total": "13"
        },
        {
            "ab_yearly_total": "746"
        },
        {
            "d_yearly_total": "233"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm parsing the JSON here:

```
// JSON from Server Actions
- (NSString *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:30];
    // Fetch the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    // Construct a String around the Data from the response
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }



- (id)objectWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    NSString *jsonString = [self stringWithUrl:url];

    // Parse the JSON into an Object
    return [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];
    }
- (NSDictionary *)downloadTotals {
    id totals = [self objectWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/totals.json"]];
    NSDictionary *totalsfeed = (NSDictionary *)totals;
    return totalsfeed;
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you parsing the JSON? What library are you using (e.g. SBJSON or YAJL)?

Comment: Your post gives no indication as to whether or not you're rolling your own JSON parser or have sourced one. There are enough good ones out there that I'd not roll my own. [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) works great for me.

Comment: I updated the answer to include where I'm parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`totals` is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects, so `[totals valueForKey:@"d_monthly_total"]` does not make sense.  Instead, to get `d_monthly_total`, you should do:

```
NSDictionary *dMonthlyTotalDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[totals objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"NEW TOTALS: %@", [dMonthlyTotalDictionary objectForKey:"d_monthly_total"]);
```

To iterate through totals, do:

```
for(NSDictionary *myDict in totals) {
    for(NSString *key in myDict) {
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", key, [myDict objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the NSDictionary and NSArray the wrong way around for the JSON you show here - wouldn't you expect the NSArray to be the outer container?

Answer (score 0):

If you can control your JSON feed, you should merge these totals into a single has, e.g.:

```
{"ab_grand_total": "2217",
 "ab_grand_total": "2217",
 "d_grand_total": "1096"
}
```

and then load it as an NSDictionary instead of an NSArray.

Comment: Well, in that case, you'll just have to iterate through the array, checking each if each NSDictionary has the key you're looking for with [yourDict objectForKey:@"d_monthly_total"] != nil.